# Get systemd's default limits

Tags: linux, limit, systemd, sles

is there a way to find out the default values of the parameter which are set in the /etc/systemd/system.conf file?

The manual page of systemd-system.conf just says:

```
When run as system instance systemd reads the configuration file
system.conf, otherwise user.conf. These configuration files contain a
few settings controlling basic manager operations.
```

The variables are outcommented (in user.conf + system.conf) and the file /etc/security/limits.conf is ignored by systemd.

So, what are the default values? Are they all set to unlimited?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

```
systemctl show
```

:)